# Python server-client

Tags: python, networking

I need some help. I have a simple server:

```
host="localhost"                
port=4447

from socket import *                
import thread

def func():
    while 1:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if not data: 
            continue
        else: 

            print("%s said: %s")%(player, data)

    conn.close()

s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))                  


s.listen(2)                 
print("Waiting for clients on localhost, port %s")%port
while 1:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    player = addr[1]
    print(conn)
    thread.start_new_thread(func,())
```

And a simple client:

```
import socket

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 4447

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

while 1:
    data = raw_input("Input: ")
    s.send(data)
```

So when I connect to the server I can type anything and it is printed in the server's terminal. When I open another terminal and start second client I can also type anything and it is sent to the server, but when I go back to the first client's terminal and type several messages, it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Client.py", line 18, in <module>
    s.send(data)
socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

So I fixed that with adding `conn` as a parameter in `func()`, but I don't understand why this error happened? Could anyone please explain it to me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `func`, apart from needing a better name, uses global state in your program to communicate with a client.  No matter how many threads you start to handle client connections, there's still only one global `conn` variable.  Each time a new client connects, your main thread loop rebinds `conn` to the new connection.  The old socket is thrown away and automatically closed by the Python runtime.

You can fix this by removing the use of global variables to track per-connection state.  A better route to explore, though, is [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/).